# Animating using shape keys, not animating

Tags: animation, shape-keys

There are actually quite a few posts of this question, but apparently I'm having a different problem. All i want is for my character to slowly open his eyes using the shape keys. I set frame 1 with eyes closed. then frame 30 with eyes open. When I go back to frame one, it doesn't reset to the closed eyes and when i hit play nothing happens. Does anyone possibly have a solution on why this may be happening??

Comment: I'm quite sure you forgot to set keyframes, happened to all of us :)
See the docs https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/introduction.html or watch a tutorial on keyframing basics (you'll find plenty yourself on youtube)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out how to get my eyes to slowly open the way i wanted them to. Instead of going to the object data, setting the values and inserting the key frames from there, I instead went into the dope sheet editor, and set the values in the shape key editor which automatically created the key frames for me (as long as i had the right frame set when changing the values.)